# How to fix NoClassDefFoundError on SpringApplication (Pivotal)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud

I've built a SpringBoot 2.1.5.RELEASE application using STS. Runs fine from STS. Dependencies downloaded into my .m2. Everything looks OK so far.

This application is packaged as a jar. I added main class using pom property. Manifest looks OK.

Now, I push this to Pivotal. It picks up java_buildpack_offline and appears to be installing but dies with

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.

---

I'm new to cloud, so I'm hoping I'm missing a step somewhere. It just doesn't feel right to package a war with dependencies in the /lib folder. What would be the next step in sorting this out? Is there a dependency I need to include that specifically handles SpringBoot on cloud?

Comment: can you attach complete stacktrace?

Comment: Try to start your application with `java -jar target/your_app.jar` - do you have the same error?

Comment: I'll try when I'm at work next week. But I presume that this will depend on environment variables seeing any of the spring libs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your jar file is not executable. For fixing it try to add the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` plugin, I hope it will help:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        ...    
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: That's what I've done but this is effectively a fat jar. Is there no better way?

Comment: You can exclude excess dependencies. May be this info will help: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Well, no-one else is commenting, so I'll accept this answer because it does work. I just feel that these dependencies should be downloaded/retrieved from cache at the time of install. But since I'm new to cloud, I'll keep quiet.

Comment: Hi! I've found this solution also: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-thin-jar. Check it, maybe it will useful.